# Android Async inside a OnGroupClickListener function

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Exapandable Listview that needs the child rows to be added dynamically when someone clicks on a group row. Best way was to send a AsyncHttp request to my server and the server responds with a json which I parse into and Object. The problem with this is that I need to return true on the OnClickGroupListener if json is empty and or false if json has data. How would I go bout doing this?

***UPDATE************

I added the Following to my code:

```
    private boolean childrenLoaded;
 public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(!childrenLoaded){
                getChildren(i);
            }else{
              return false;
            }
           return true;
        }

public void getChildren(int position){
    //HttpAsync request here
    onSuccess(json){
        childrenLoaded = true;
        if (json has data){
        listview.performclick(arguments for perform click);
        }else{
        exit
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `OnGroupClickListener` documentation, it appears you only need to return true if the click was handled by you.

> **Returns**
>
> True if the click was handled

If you would like to track some other true/false outcome (such as the emptyness of a json response) it should conceptually and literally be handled elsewhere.  For example, you could have a small progress indicator that shows on the list item when the click happens (return `true` because you obviously handled the click), and stop the progress bar when your network request completes with either a success or a failure.